# Why have SQL Server services disappeared from services.msc?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, availability-groups, windows-server

I'm running an `Always On Availability Group` with 2 `SQL Server 2014` database servers in an AD domain. Updates are supplied to all domain servers via `WSUS`. Also have a third MS Reporting Services server that is not part of the group.

This morning, with DB01 as primary and DB02 as secondary, I installed `Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2-CU12) (KB4130489) - 12.0.5589.7 (X64)` on all three servers. Went in ok on the report server and DB02, Failed to go in on DB01 (error 86D80017). Instead of troubleshooting the error, I decided to manually install KB4130489. Manual install on DB01 went ok. AOHA Dashboard shows all is ok. What is weird is that on DB01, the `Services Management Console` UI does not show any of the expected `SQL-Server` related services (5 of them in my case). SQL Server Configuration Manager shows services (as expected - see screen shot below). They just don't show up in services.msc

Why have SQL Server services disappeared from services.msc on DB01?

SQL Server Configuration Manager shows services (as expected)

[image: SQL Server Configuration Manager]

However, services.msc does NOT show services as expected (they should appear right after "Spot Verifier" service

[image: services.msc]

Comment: sorry - I wasn't clear: the SQL Server services are missing from services.msc. See updates in my question. BTW: This db server has only one instance of SQL Server (a default instance). This instance is the only one ever installed on this machine

Comment: Did you try looking for 'MSSQLSERVER'?  I've seen it do that before in services.msc.

Comment: @KrisGruttemeyer: Just looked - no joy (not there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't explain why this cured my problem, but while using services.msc on the computer that wasn't showing the SQl Server services, I clicked on Action->Connect To Another Computer. I connected to the other DB server (where SQl Server services appear ok on its services.msc) and then I connected back to  he local computer (DB01). The SQL Server services now appear as expected

Comment: Did you tried F5/Refresh and did not help?

Comment: Yes, many times :-)

Answer (score 0):

This happens if you select 'connect to another computer' in services. The application remembers this as a new default and shows the remote computer even after reboot. I had to manually select 'connect to another computer' and select 'local computer' to change it back.